# Examples of different kind of workflows in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I am expanding my knowledge of sharepoint. When I googled 'examples of list,site, reusable workflows for sharepoint', all I got was the methods to create these workflows with a single example. There isn't clear explanation on which workflows to use on which situation.

It is often confusing which workflow to use for given business logic. For example I have to design a workflow that is going to carry-forward the leaves from current year to next year. I thought to use list workflow to achieve this but I also think it will be better to use reusable workflow to achieve this as the business logic seems similar to an email notification task:
https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-2013-reusable-workflow/

Which workflow would be best to achieve my goal to implement given business logic?

Also it will be helpful if someone could give me few scenarios on the different workflows.

Answer (score 1):

A List workflow is associated with a single list and is triggered when the list item is added or edited. Once triggered, it can interact with the current list item, or with other lists. (You could create a "new item" alert that is unique to a single list.)

A Reusable workflow is associated with a Content Type and is available to all list items based on that Content Type. It is triggered and processed the same as a List workflow. (You could create a "new task alert" for all new items based on the Tasks Content Type.)

A Site workflow is not tied to a single list and is manually triggered by a user. This is often used to create a set of list entries in one or more lists for a new customer or project.

As you mentioned SharePoint Online, also take a look a Flow as the next generation of workflows. These are generally triggered the same as a List workflow.

> a workflow that is going to carry-forward the leaves from current year to next year

Is this a manually triggered event? Such as once a year on January 1st? If so, then consider a Site workflow.

Comment: no it will be auto triggered

Comment: What will trigger it? A user updating a list item?

Comment: i will trigger it by the workflow when I check if the date is last date of year